# How to handle reactions in Telegram bots?

Tags: api, bots, telegram

I want to create bot for Telegram, which can handle events for message Is it possible ways to handle it?

I didn't find any information about than in official Tg API docs.

Comment: Looks like bots cant interact with reactions right now, this part of functionality is no in the bot api.